# How to pass a form as the parameter of a function vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Currently in VB.NET I have two public subs like so:

```
Public Sub addmember1()
    'Stuff
End Sub

Public Sub furtherinfo1()
    'suff
End Sub
```

I haven't included the code where "'stuff" is as it is very long and is **exactly the same** in each sub, however the underlying the principle remains the same.

A certain sub is ran depending on a boolean value. like so...

```
If add_member = True Then
    addmember1()
ElseIf add_member = False Then
    furtherinfo1()
End If
```

How would I use one function to carry out the same procedure as above? (my current solution works but involves repeating the same section of code twice )

I tried the following however was unsuccessful

```
Public Function forms(ByVal frm As Windows.Forms.Form)
    'stuff
End Function
```

and then run the function like so... (addmember and furtherinfo are the two forms I am working with)

```
        If add_member = True Then
            forms(addmember)
        ElseIf add_member = False Then
            forms(furtherinfo)
        End If
```

here is the paste bin of all the code for context it's in modual and I want to use it for writing information to a word document. Lines 20-71, 76-128, 160-164 is what I am on about.

http://pastebin.com/xWD0RBuh

Comment: `unsuccessful` means...?

Comment: why do you have multiple sub routines that have "exactly the same" implementation?  Wouldn't it make sense to reuse one version?

Comment: ... with some deciphering attempts I guess he means that he's doing the same code with two different form objects (hard coded), so it's not really _exactly_ the same (but that's a guess).

Comment: It didn't work I get the error "txtUsername is not a member of system.Windows.Forms.form"

Comment: I recommend rephrasing the question so people who are not familiar with your project can understand what you are seeking to do.

Comment: I don't know how else to explain it, I have put a link to the paste bin of it.

Comment: Forms are classes, so the type will matter. system.Windows.Forms.form is the base type all the forms in your app are built from, but the Form1 (or whatever) in your app is *different* because it includes a `txtUsername` control.  The specifics of what you are trying to do has a bearing on whether how you are doing it is a good idea to start with.

Comment: Does that mean it is not possible? Or is there another way around it?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983613%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: you do not need to pass a form in order to pass the *data* on the form

Comment: Your concern should be about optimizing `StrToAdd = "Firstname:  " & FurtherInfo.txtName.Text
        wrdSelection.TypeText(StrToAdd)
        InsertLines(1)` part, which is repeated a couple dozen of times.

Comment: ye, one thing at a time though. This printing process that im working on now is only a tiny fraction of the whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the form object to a Sub() in a module as below

Module Printing

```
Dim StrToAdd As String
Sub MySub(ByVal frm As Form)
    'The first line is your code
    StrToAdd = "Firstname:  " & addmember.txtName.Text
    'Change it to as below using frm.Controls("controlname").Text
    StrToAdd = "Firstname:  " & frm.Controls("txtName").Text
End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code at http://pastebin.com/xWD0RBuh it seems you have a global module with multiple sub routines.  Each sub routine has references to controls (such as text boxes) on a form instance.  This means each global module sub routine needs to have access to this form instance.

You have only copied in part of the application - the global module, but you have not copied in the form definition.  I presume you have a form called addmember, but I don't see it in the example - aside from references in the global module.

Not sure how you use the sub routines - probably a click of a button.  If it were me, I would create a class object with properties that hold the data to pass around - one property for each control on the form you want to print.  On the click of the button, I would create an instance of the class and copy the values from the form controls into the class properties.  I would then pass the instance of the class to the sub routines, and I would alter the sub routines to refer to an instance of the class instead of an instance of a form.  That would provide a level abstraction between the form (UI) and the behavior (the sub routines that print).  I may even go "crazy" and use an interface.

Does your code compile as-is?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that your two Forms are two different classes. Even though you named your controls
the same, you can't just access them simply by `frm.txtUsername`.

What you could do is iterate through all controls of each form und find them by name:

```
Public Sub DoStuff(frm As Form)
    Dim txtUsername As TextBox = GetControlByName(frm, "txtUsername")
    txtUsername.Text = "Hello World"
End Sub

Private Function GetControlByName(container As Control, name As String) As Control
    Dim retVal As Control = Nothing
    If Not TryGetControlByName(container, name, retVal) Then Throw New ApplicationException("control not found")
    Return retVal
End Function

Private Function TryGetControlByName(container As Control, name As String, ByRef ctl As Control) As Boolean
    For Each item As Control In container.Controls
        If item.Name = name Then
            ctl = item
            Return True
        End If

        'If item is a Container (like GroupBox, Panel) check its children
        If TryGetControlByName(item, name, ctl) Then Return True
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

If you want to get really fancy you could define a Class with the common Controls and fill them via a little
bit of reflection magic. Though this might be overkill:

```
Public Sub DoStuff2(frm As Form)
    Dim wrapper As New CommonForm(frm)
    wrapper.txtUsername.Text = "Hello Wolrd"
End Sub

Public Class CommonForm
    Public Property txtUsername As TextBox
    Public Property txtFoo As TextBox
    Public Property txtBar As TextBox
    'Add more Controls here...

    Public Sub New(frm As Form)
        For Each item In Me.GetType().GetProperties()
            Dim value = GetControlByName(frm, item.Name)
            item.SetValue(Me, value, Nothing)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function GetControlByName(container As Control, name As String) As Control
        Dim retVal As Control = Nothing
        If Not TryGetControlByName(container, name, retVal) Then Throw New ApplicationException("control not found")
        Return retVal
    End Function

    Private Function TryGetControlByName(container As Control, name As String, ByRef ctl As Control) As Boolean
        For Each item As Control In container.Controls
            If item.Name = name Then
                ctl = item
                Return True
            End If

            'If item is a Container (like GroupBox, Panel) check its children
            If TryGetControlByName(item, name, ctl) Then Return True
        Next
        Return False
    End Function

End Class
```